# Globle error filter in node js

Tags: node.js

I am working on node from last 2-3 months on a project. Now I want to handle errors from a single point in node. For example : I have several api functions in my project. Many of them are taking _id as an api input. I need to parse this id using mongoose objectid before using in query. Now if the format of _id is not valid, it will throw the casting error. It could be handled by mongoose object isvalid property. But my purpose is that, at any place if it is not handled in code I want to catch the error and log it to my log file and send a common message like 'error occurs' to the UI. I want to add a common error handler for all the api that do the logging and error handling for my api, like we use .net MVC - error handler filer through the application.
I have tried using domain. But in domain.on('error',func(err){}); it is not working. I put my api functions call in domain.run();
If any body have any suggestion for me, please let me know.

Comment: I found a simple answer here. http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [domain](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) module, if your app powered by express you can use the package - [express-domain-middleware](https://github.com/brianc/node-domain-middleware)